# gzseek(zlib) fails when offset is too large (greater than range of signed int 2^32)?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I am using zlib 1.2.11. When i use gzseek with offset greater than the range of a signed int (half of 2^32) ; I get bytes_read as -1. Is there any way to use 64 bit offset.

Here is an excerpt from the definition of gzseek64 from gzlib.c

---

```
if (state->mode == GZ_READ) {
        n = GT_OFF(state->x.have) || (z_off64_t)state->x.have > offset ?(unsigned)offset : state->x.have;
        state->x.have -= n;
        state->x.next += n;
        state->x.pos += n;
        offset -= n;
    }
```

---

here n is unsigned int which can hold only 32 bits...even if my offset was 64 bits how would n hold that value.... Please correct me if i am wrong

More Findings:
After declaring the macro Z_LARGE64 ... gzseek accepts 64 bit offset but ...
When i pass a large offset the bytes seeked returned is a **large negative** value and i think it has to do with the **__int64 to unsigned int** conversion

Comment: On what? Linux? Windows? macOS? How was it compiled?

Comment: I am using windows. I understand that there is some way to link the gzseek calls to gzseek64 is this available only in 32 bit DLLs? Because when i try to build zlib 1.2.11 there is no gzseek64 function in the DLL (or so the dependency walker says).

Comment: _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE is defined but gzseek64 is still not exported am i missing something

Comment: That means the offset can take a value upto 2^ 64 right. but when my offset in gzseek goes past 2,147,483,648 (half of 2^32 ) the bytes_seeked becomes -1 (error)

Comment: Of what type is the variable you are using as the second argument of `gzseek()`?

Comment: gzseek(origFile, start, SEEK_SET); start is uint64.. Should i be using z_off64_t

Comment: sizeof(z_off_t) is 32 bits.. in zconf.h i see that off_t is defined as long. which is only 32 bits then how is off_t going to be 64 bits?

Comment: in windows off_t is defined as long in sys\types.h which is only 32 bits

Comment: I see now that you would need to use `gzseek64()` on Windows, which will use `z_off64_t`, defined as `__int64`. It should be compiled, but the prototype will not be available in zlib.h by default. You can `#define Z_LARGE64` to get those prototypes.

Comment: I added Z_LARGE64 to the compiler options but the compiled dll doesnt seem to have gzseek64() exported.

Comment: You would use `Z_LARGE64` not when compiling the library but rather when compiling the application. The `#define Z_LARGE64` should precede the `#include "zlib.h"` in the application.

Comment: @MarkAdler This is not working for me because the gzseek64() is not exported in the zlib1.dll. I am getting linker error when i try to use the lib to build my application

Comment: If `gzseek()` is being exported, then so should `gzseek64()`. Both functions are defined with `__declspec(dllexport)`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you defining `ZLIB_DLL` when compiling?

Comment: Sorry.No Iam not defining ZLIB_DLL, should i be ?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I have edited zconf.h so that z_off_t is now __int64 if compiled with LARGEFILE64 option and off_t otherwise. By default z_off_t was defined as off_t (which would resolve to 32 bits only ). I think this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Compile the library with `Z_LARGE64` and then use that lib to build your application. In the application include `Z_LARGE64` before `#include "zlib.h"`. Then use `gzseek64()`

Comment: I tried compiling the library with Z_LARGE64 but the library or DLL built doesnt have the **gzseek64** exported. I confirmed this using Dependency Walker So when i try to compile my application I get linker error.